# Why did my table disappear from pg_catalog.pg_class? (Alternatively, how to find primary key columns?)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

Using postgres 10.4.2 from debian (in fact, using the postgresql docker container.)

I have a few schema files that I apply in order. These create, drop, and alter tables to follow evolution over time of the schema.

Then, I run a program which selects table definitions out of pg_catalog to generate code wrappers for the existing tables. This has worked fine until now. (The code for this program is developed by me and thus highly suspect, though!)

I recently added "alter table customer add field customer_stem varchar(255) not null default ''" and "create index on customer(customer_stem)" to a new schema file.
Now, the customer table is no longer found in the query for tables to find primary keys.

The query I run is this:

```
    select c.relname, i.indkey 
    from pg_catalog.pg_index i 
    inner join pg_catalog.pg_class c 
      on i.indrelid=c.relfilenode 
    inner join pg_catalog.pg_tables t 
      on c.relname=t.tablename 
    where t.schemaname='public' 
      and i.indisprimary;
```

This should tell me which indices are primary keys for my tables.
However, the "customer" table now fell out of this query -- the `relfilenode` in pg_class no longer matches anything in pg_index.

```
# select relname, relfilenode from pg_catalog.pg_class where relname='customer';
 relname  | relfilenode
----------+-------------
 customer |       16512

observe_dev=# select count(1) from pg_catalog.pg_index where indrelid=16512;
 count
-------
     0
(1 row)
```

There should be both a primary key and a secondary index for this table!

So, my guess is that the "alter table" statement somehow changes the ID of the 'customer' class such that it's no longer matching the "pg_index" table, but that seems really weird. PSQL still knows what the definition is:

```
                                                    Table "public.customer"
    Column     |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |        Default        | Storage  | Stats target | Description
---------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 customer_id   | integer                |           | not null |                       | plain    |              |
 customer_name | character varying(255) |           | not null |                       | extended |              |
 customer_stem | character varying(255) |           | not null | ''::character varying | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "customer_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (customer_id)
    "customer_customer_name_idx" btree (customer_name)
    "customer_customer_stem_idx" btree (customer_stem)
Referenced by:
```

there are a number of foreign key relations, too.

So, one of two things are happening:
1) The alter table somehow causes the pg_catalog to stop keeping up to date (this seems unlikely.)
2) My research into how to find the columns of the primary key of each of my tables is wrong, and I'm looking at the wrong tables/columns

It's very likely it's 2), but if so, how SHOULD I go about finding that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should probably be joining `pg_index` on the `pg_class.oid` column, ie:

```
select c.relname, i.indkey 
from pg_catalog.pg_index i 
inner join pg_catalog.pg_class c 
  on i.indrelid=c.oid  -- << HERE change c.relfilenode to c.oid 
left join pg_catalog.pg_tables t 
  on c.relname=t.tablename 
where t.schemaname='public' 
  and i.indisprimary;
```

Note that `oid` is hidden from the output of `select * from pg_catalog.pg_class` and `\d pg_catalog.pg_class` in `psql`, but it is there as a "hidden" column.

I was able to replicate your issue locally, so I'm guessing that adding the column or index changes the value of `relfilenode` in the table's `pg_class` record.

See also https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Retrieve_primary_key_columns which details how to query primary keys - it might be worth adding in the join to `pg_attribute`. Slightly OT but I found it worth noting that `'my_table_name'::regclass` gets converted to the appropriate `pg_class.oid` by PostgreSQL. You can actually test (and get any table's `oid`)  by running `select 'my_table_name'::regclass::oid`!

Just for interest's sake, I also did some further testing to determine exactly which table change is triggering the `pg_class.relfilenode` change. It appears that the `alter table add column ...`default ''` is the cause.

When a column is added without specifying a `default`, the value stays the same. The following script demonstrates the behaviour:

```
create table test (id uuid, col1 varchar(255));
select c.oid, c.relfilenode, c.relname from pg_catalog.pg_class c where c.oid = 'test'::regclass;
alter table test add column col2 varchar(255) not null;
select c.oid, c.relfilenode, c.relname from pg_catalog.pg_class c where c.oid = 'test'::regclass;
alter table test add column col3 varchar(255) not null default '';
select c.oid, c.relfilenode, c.relname from pg_catalog.pg_class c where c.oid = 'test'::regclass;
drop table test;
```

So it appears that adding a column with default changes the relation's filenode for some reason. It's also worth reading the [PostgreSQL docs on `pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/catalog-pg-class.html) for more details on `relfilenode` and other attributes.

Comment: The "some reason" is that the table has to be rewritten. This will improve in PostgreSQL v11.

Answer (score 1):

Don't join the catalogs on the name-texts, you only need numerical id's for joining (the names in the catalogs *are* case significant, which can only confuse you). Also: you don't need the pg_tables catalog; it is only a view on pg_class

WRT the disappearing catalog-entries: did you commit your alter table DDL? DDLs need to perform some trickery on the catalogs to hide the new version from other sessions.

---

```
select c.relname, i.indkey,i.indexrelid , i.indrelid  
    from pg_catalog.pg_index i 
    inner join pg_catalog.pg_class c 
      on i.indrelid=c.relfilenode 
where c.relname='target';
```

Comment: I need to look up by name, because it's the names of the tables I work with!
I did commit the DDL. Specifically, I ran it by piping a script to psql, and when that exits, it commits.